# RxJs timer subscribe not called in Angular component

Tags: angular, rxjs

Subscribe call back of Rxjs timer is not called within Angular component. The code seemed to work fine in a simple typescript file via node but the same would not work within the angular component.

Here is the code which worked in node

```
import { timer, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

function watchForJSFilesLoad() {
  let _stop = new Subject<void>();
  let observable$ = timer(0, 500).pipe(
    map((n) => <any>{n}),
    takeUntil(_stop)
  );

  observable$.subscribe((n) => {
    console.log(n.n);
    if (n.n == 50) {
      console.warn('stop polling.')
      _stop.next();
    }
  });
}

watchForJSFilesLoad();
```

And here is the angular component code, which has essentially the same thing

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("pdfViewer") pdfViewer: PdfJsViewerComponent;
  @Input() pdfUrl: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.warn("inline rendering component loaded");
    this.watchForJSFilesLoad();
  }

  watchForJSFilesLoad() {
    console.warn("watch for js files load");
    let _stop = new Subject<void>();
    let observable$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      map(() => <any>{}),
      takeUntil(_stop)
    );

    observable$.subscribe(() => {
      console.log("checking if loaded");
      if (condition) {
        console.warn("stop polling.");
        _stop.next();
      }
    });
  }

}
```

I cannot see console logs within the subscribe.
Am i missing something?

Thanks.

rxjs@6.2.2

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" with your code. It should work, so I guess it's better if you try to make a minimal reproducible example in stackblitz

Comment: This code should work, at least it will print `checking if loaded` once. check you `condition`  once.

Comment: it is printing `watch for js files load`. But it does not print `checking if loaded` even once.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the above code into Stackblitz and it worked in that it displays:

[image]

It *is* displaying "checking if loaded". So maybe there is something else wrong somewhere else?

You can find the stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-210824-deborahk

Comment: it worked for me as well on stackblitz. I am trying to add more things to the stackblitz, to bring it as close to original component so that i can share it here to get a better idea. Will update soon.